# Why that Git always commit my unstaged files?

Tags: git

Git auto commit my staged and unstaged changes, either use git CLI or Sourcetree. I only use `git add "file path"`,and It shows one file to commit when I check with `git status`, but after I use `git commit -m "message"`, It commit my two files.

my git version 2.32.0

Comment: From what you're describing, this sounds like totally incorrect behaviour from git.  Could you paste the offending entry from `git whatchanged` into your question?  It should show only one file, prefixed with `A` that shows it was freshly added.

Comment: Do you have local hooks activated ? can you paste the output of the 2 commands : `git config core.hooksPath`, and `ls .git/hooks` (run from your repository's root directory) ?

Comment: Also this is why using `-m` is evil (outside of automated scripts).
It takes away your chance to double-check what git is *really* going to commit :P

Comment: A collegue of mine has the same problem. `git config core.hooksPath` doesn't return anything and in the `hooks` there are only the `*.sample` files. Also if commiting without `-m` the commit template still only shows the added files. He is running `2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)`. Interestingly enough if he runs `git restore --soft HEAD~` only the added files are shown as staged. Also I didn't see anything suspicious in `~/.gitconfig` or `.git/config`

Comment: This does not happen in a clean repo `git init; touch file1 file2; git add file1; git commit` works just fine. But if he freshly clones the problematic repo he still has the same issue.

Comment: @AndyJ It shows two file with `M`. @Micheal Yes, that looks like the same situation with me. But I tried to re-clone before, it normal for a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found that it is caused by [pre-commit](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit). I remove that and it works now. But that is weird, I will try more test and maybe make an issue report.

Comment: Remember to accept your own answer, if that was the one that worked.

Comment: Is there an option somewhere in pre-commit that disables this behavior?